# AngularJS - Disabling ng-href on certain items in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating a list of events using ng-repeat, and I'd like each event to link to another location, which I've done successfully. However, this ng-href is also being applied to list dividers, which I'd rather avoid. Is there any way to conditionally apply a ng-href if a condition is true? I thought about using ng-click instead and having that handle the URL, but then the event list item won't look like a link anymore.

Here's my HTML thus far.

```
<ion-item class="item" ng-class="{'item-divider': isDivider(event), 'item-icon-right': !isDivider(event)}" ng-repeat="event in events" ng-href="#/app/{{channel}}/{{event.id}}">
    <h2>{{event.title}}</h2>
    <p ng-if="valid(event.start_date)">{{showDate(event.start_date)}}</p>
    <i ng-if="!isDivider(event)" class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: `ng-click="$event.preventDefault()"` on the divider.

Comment: You *can* use `ng-click`; just use CSS to style the event list item as if it were a link. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't.

You need something along these lines:

```
<ion-item class="item" ng-class="{'item-divider': isDivider(event), 'item-icon-right': !isDivider(event)}" ng-repeat="event in events">
  <div ng-if="!isDivider(event)" ng-href="#/app/{{channel}}/{{event.id}}">
    <h2>{{event.title}}</h2>
    <p ng-if="valid(event.start_date)">{{showDate(event.start_date)}}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="isDivider(event)">
    <h2>{{event.title}}</h2>
    <p ng-if="valid(event.start_date)">{{showDate(event.start_date)}}</p>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

This way a divider won't behave nor look like a link.

Answer (score 0):

meta: "ionic ion-item conditional href"

This is my solution to conditionally have a href only if a list item has sub elements.

note that "ion-item" is only a clickable element if the href is set, therefore there is no need to modify css classes.

```js
<ion-view view-title="Checklists">
  <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
          <div ng-repeat="item in checklists">
              
     <!--only shown if the list has no sub lists, not clickable as there is no href-->
     <ion-item ng-if="item.sublists === null">
                  {{item.index}}. {{item.name}}
              </ion-item>
     
     <!--only shown if the list has sub lists, clickable -->
              <ion-item ng-if="item.sublists !== null" href="#/app/checklists/{{item.id}}/sublists">
                  {{item.index}}. {{item.name}}
                  <span class="item-note" style="margin-right: -33px;">
                      <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
                  </span>
              </ion-item>
     
          </div>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```